# I want to render a json message when a /post attempts to set the id of an database model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have a test that sets the post object @emergencies.id to 1 and I wish to render the 'message' => 'found unpermitted parameter: id'. I was wondering if theres a validation I can place in the model to render this message when the id is mass assigned. Ive been searching everywhere and there seems to be no solution. I was thinking of creating a method in the create action in the emergencies_controller that checks if the value id has been set and then I render that message but it doesn't seem very clean at all.

## TEST

```
test 'POST /emergencies/ cannot set id' do
  post '/emergencies', emergency: { id: 1, fire_severity: 1, police_severity: 2,   medical_severity: 3 }

  assert_equal 422, response.status
  assert_equal({ 'message' => 'found unpermitted parameter: id' }, JSON.parse(body))
end
```

Comment: You can catch mass assign exceptions and render the JSON as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an exception to handle this situation, and then catch it in the application controller

```
class UnprocessableEntityException < StandardError
  attr_accessor :message
  def initialize(msg)
    @message = msg
    super
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from UnprocessableEntityException do |e|
    render :status => 422, :json => {:message => e.message}
  end 
end
```

Then in your create action:

```
def create
  if params[:emergency][:id]
    raise UnprocessableEntityException.new('found unpermitted parameter: id')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails actually has a built-in exception with a message format that matches what you are testing for (leading me to think the test's writers had this exception in mind).  You can configure Rails to raise **ActionController::UnpermittedParameters** when params are filtered out by strong parameters with:

```
# config/application.rb
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

You can then rescue from this error:

```
class EmergenciesController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActionController::UnpermittedParameters,
              with: :catch_unpermitted_params

  (...)

  def catch_unpermitted_params
    render json: { message: $ERROR_INFO.message }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

It can also be abstracted up to the ApplicationController level.

(Good luck with railschallenge! This is the solution I've written for my submission.)

Comment: Excellent .Thanks a lot! your solution is actually very good.